# Unreachable browser exception and connection refused in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am using selenium web driver with Ubuntu and Firefox browser(version 47). While running my java script Firefox window appears and suddenly gets close. And on console it shows following exceptions.

```
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot instantiate class eBastaSearchOptions.QuickBuy
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryIm`enter code here`pl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:40)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:382)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:295)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:118)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:183)
    at org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.<init>(TestNGClassFinder.java:128)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:416)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:242)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:212)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:166)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_9_7$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_9_7.java:26)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_9_7$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_9_7.java:59)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:587)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:161)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:114)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1290)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1277)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1131)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:137)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:29)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
System info: host: 'VISHAL', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-88-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_80'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:665)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
    at eBastaSearchOptions.QuickBuy.<init>(QuickBuy.java:20)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:7055 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:151)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:144)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:90)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.execute(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:160)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver$LazyCommandExecutor.execute(FirefoxDriver.java:380)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:644)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:74)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)
    ... 48 more
```

I uninstalled Firefox completly and installed it again but still I am facing this problem. Previously below java script was working fine. But suddenly it started showing me above error.
My script is as below-

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import eBastaTestingClasses.GenerateReport;

public class QuickBuy 
{


    @Test (priority = 1)
    public void quickSearch()
    {

        try
        {
            WebDriver wd = new FirefoxDriver();
            wd.get("http://14.139.112.73:8001/local-test/");
            wd.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='edit-field-ebasta-name-value']")).sendKeys("test31march2016");
            wd.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='edit-submit-quick-buy']")).click();
            if (wd.getCurrentUrl() == "http://14.139.112.73:8001/local-test/")
            {
                System.out.println("Pass");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Fail");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this problem. Same script is working fine with Chrome driver. But I want to fix this in only Firefox.

Comment: The Selenium 2.53.0 with Firefox version 47 is a open issue and it was raised in Github. [Click here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2110) to know more about the issue.Once the issue is closed in github you can start work with the latest version of Firefox. Till that try with the **Firefox 46.0.1**

Comment: Thanks..I revert back to 46 and wow it started working fine now.

Comment: Unless you want to crash your application while it runs, Use Chrome WebDriver.Because It don't have these compatibility issues and it runs smoothly

Comment: The issue has been fixed in Firefox 47.0.1. I have downloaded it, installed in /opt, pointed my Selenium to that installation and it works now `new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxBinary(new File("/opt/firefox-47.0.1/firefox")), firebugProfile());`